# Session in PHP Function

Tags: php, function, session

I'm new in php i create one function from where i'm login my session now i want to use this function for multiple time like for admin login too how i can use this function for multiple session. I updated my answer as per instruction of **PacMan**. Rightnow I'm doing it like this:

**Code For USER & Admin Login:**

```
//Check Wheather User Logged in or Not

if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedID']) && !empty($_SESSION['LoggedID'])){
  $tableName = "prd_rgistration";
  $id = $_SESSION['UserLogin'];
}else{
  $tableName = "user_register";
  $id = $_SESSION['AdminID'];
}
    //Check Wheather User Logged in or Not
    function Logged(){
        if(LoggedIn()){
            global $conn;
            return $conn->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM ' + $tableName + ' WHERE id = \'%d\'',$id))->fetchObject();
        }else{
            return (object)array();
        }
    } 
    function LoggedIn(){
        return isset($id) && intval($id);
    }
    function redirect($Location){
        header(sprintf('Location: %s',$Location),true,301);
        exit;
    }

    if(LoggedIn()){
        $User = Logged();
    }
```

**Admin Login Page Code**

```
if($email_err == "" && $password_err == ""){
        $Code = 0;
        try{
            $get_data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `user_register` WHERE `reg_email` = '$email' AND `reg_pass` = '$password' LIMIT 1");
            if($get_data->rowCount() > 0){
                $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $get_data->fetchObject()->id;    
                 redirect('/domain.com/temp/admin/index.php');
            }else{
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-info">Invalid Email/Password</div>';
            }
        }catch(PDOException $E){
            $Code = $E->getCode();
        }
    }
```

**User Login Page Code**

```
if($email_err == '' && $user_pass_err == ''){
        $Code = 0;
        try{
            $get_data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `prd_rgistration` WHERE `email_db` = '$email' AND `password_db` = '$user_pass' LIMIT 1");
            if($get_data->rowCount() > 0){
                $_SESSION['UserLogin'] = $get_data->fetchObject()->id;  
                 redirect('/domain.com/temp/index.php');
                //redirect('/domain.com/index.php');
            }else{
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-info">Invalid Email/Password</div>';
            }
        }catch(PDOException $E){
            $Code = $E->getCode();
        }
    }
```

Now It's giving Error Undefined **AdminID** and also not login user.

Comment: Did you created 2 tables? One for admin and one for user?  You need to create one table and than add column admin and assign for example 1 if is admin and 0 if not. Than you can use same function for each group of users.

Comment: Actually before I was doing the same thing but my PM want i should create in separate.

Comment: As far as I know than you can't use same function for different tables...

Comment: Eventually make query for both tables and than if user is in any start session. Than check in which table is user.

Comment: i marked up the answer on my previous question check out this. I only marked up those people which answer was helpful for me. @Anant

Comment: yeah here i vote up all of them except first answer which was from jiboulex  because it's useless for me. I needed only `foreach loop`

Comment: @Anant i also voted up your answer as well and now made you best answer now is that ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you to follow this procedure it may be helpful , by changing the table name to a variable

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedID']) && !empty($_SESSION['LoggedID'])){
  $tableName = "prd_rgistration";
  $id = $_SESSION['LoggedID'];
}else if(isset($_SESSION['adminID']) && !empty($_SESSION['adminID'])){
  $tableName = "admin";
  $id = $_SESSION['adminID']
}
//Check Wheather User Logged in or Not

function Logged(){
    if(LoggedIn()){
        global $conn;
        return $conn->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM '$tableName' WHERE id = \'%d\'',$id))->fetchObject();
    }else{
        return (object)array();
    }
}
```

and here is it you have parametred only one function for both of usses admin and user login

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: this line is giving syntax error `return $conn->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM '$tableName' WHERE id = \'%d\'',$id))->fetchObject();` whenever i add variable behalf of `Table Name`

Comment: try it with FROM ' " .$tableName. " ' and let me know if it works

Comment: yeah i have updated my answer and use like this and mention what next i'm getting

Comment: another one kindly see my question again i updated with your code and with more detail

Comment: Now It's giving Error Undefined `AdminID` and also not login user. Just login `admin user`

Comment: when you log with the admin account try debug it with print_r($_SESSION) see what it's giving if is it empty or not and then you will realize from where the problem is coming cause your code is clean and logic